# Resolving static properties at runtime

Tags: c#, dynamic

I need to create a solution where static properties on a C# type are determined at runtime rather than compile time. These runtime properties need to be discovered via reflection, for example using:

```
Type mytype =type(MyType);
mytype .GetProperty(this._errorMessageResourceName, BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
```

So far I have investigated the following:

### DynamicObjects:

Is it possible with the DynamicObject in C# to intercept requests for static properties?

The TryGetMember method does not seem to intercept the method if called by reflection and from what i can tell via VS intellisense the DynamicObject is probably no meant to work with statics.

### ICustomTypeDescriptor

This exists in the System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations namespace and only works for data binding situations, I need a solution that works in the general .NET runtime.

### Modifying/Overriding the RunTimeType

Digging through the .NET code it seems like this might be an option(since System.Type is abstract) but I can't work out how this type is generated or how to override which type is loaded. (Maybe this is bad idea).

Comment: How do you plan to use such properties? Why not simply calling a static method instead of using such static properties?

Comment: We having to work with a third party piece of software that use reflection to read static properties. We are trying to avoid having to write lots of boiler plate code and we can't alter the third party code.

Comment: The question lack an example. The code, as I understood, is a part of another software to get static properties of **your** type. Why can't you simply change your type? What exactly should happens if you succeed? What boilerplate code you want to eliminate?